# Merging from the git gives an error on the xcode and project file could not be opened

Tags: ios, xcode, git, git-merge

[image]

Many time I have an issue like this when doing a merge with two branches. Any best solution for this and merging as well.
Thank You!

Comment: The easiest solution is to not keep IDE related files in your repository. Those are related just to your  instance of IDE, if you would work with other people, they could use different settings, so you would end up  either with merge conflicts or changing your setting in you IDE with every pull.

Comment: How could I do this not keep IDE related files in repo. And for current scenario how to access my project file as it shows the above mentioned alert there. Thank you!

Comment: You've mentioned that you are using git, so please take a look into this : 

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Xcode.gitignore

About your current problem with Xcode, I cannot help because I'm not an user of this IDE. Maybe re-importing the project would help ?